# jQuery/ajax - two separate API requests with combined results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, blockchain

Evening Internet World,

First post here so be gentle, i've learnt a lot from this site thus far.. and now I seek help..

I've tried a few variations of code like $when & $then, function in function, but I can't get the result I seek, it doesn't combine results. So thought best to ask away here and show my code.. Please help..

**html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="stats">
  <div class="col-4 col-12-large">
    <h4><strong>Ether contributed</strong></h4>
    <span id="eth_balance" style="font-size: 2.5em;">&mdash;</span>
    <!--<p id="total-ether-message" style="font-size:11px;"></p>-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-12-large">
    <h4><strong>Contributions in USD</strong></h4>
    <span id="token_usd" style="font-size: 2.5em;">&mdash;</span>
    <!--<p id="total-usd-message" style="font-size:11px;"></p>-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 col-12-large">
    <h4><strong>Tokens issued</strong></h4>
    <span id="token_amount" style="font-size: 2.5em;">&mdash;</span>
    <!-- <p id="total-tokens-message" style="font-size:11px;"></p> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var token = '0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d';
var address = '0xda0aed568d9a2dbdcbafc1576fedc633d28eee9a';

$.get("https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/" + token + "/" + address +'', function(data) {
    $("#eth_balance").html(Math.round(data.eth_balance).toFixed(2) + " ETH");
    $("#token_amount").html(Math.round(data.balance).toFixed(2) + " " + data.symbol);
});

$.get("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice", function(data) {
    $("#token_usd").html("$ " + Math.round(data.result.ethusd).toFixed(2));
    // Ideally I'd like to get [ data.result.ethusd x data.eth_balance ] to replace #token_usd, all wrapped in one function
    alert(data.result.ethusd)
});
```

**Or you can play here**

https://jsfiddle.net/4zwvo90n/8/

Comment: Welcome to SO! Great to see that you put some real effort into a clear and thoughtful post. Glad you got a solution. One piece of feedback I'd give is to work to make the code samples as *minimal* as possible. These are far from the most bloated we encounter here, but still quite a bit more code than absolutely necessary to illustrate your issue. Some more good tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the second ajax call inside the first, and store values from `data` in a variable that will be available to the inner function too.

Like so (second call won't work here or in a fiddle):

```js
    var token = '0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d';
    var address = '0xda0aed568d9a2dbdcbafc1576fedc633d28eee9a';

    $.get("https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/" + token + "/" + address + '', function (data) {
        var eth_balance = data.eth_balance;
        $("#eth_balance").html(Math.round(data.eth_balance).toFixed(2) + " ETH");
        $("#token_amount").html(Math.round(data.balance).toFixed(2) + " " + data.symbol);
        $.get("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice", function (data) {
            $("#token_usd").html("$ " + Math.round(data.result.ethusd * eth_balance).toFixed(2));
            // Ideally I'd like to get [ data.result.ethusd x data.eth_balance ] to replace #token_usd, all wrapped in one function
            alert(data.result.ethusd)
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="stats">
    <div class="col-4 col-12-large">
        <h4>
            <strong>Ether contributed</strong>
        </h4>
        <span id="eth_balance" style="font-size: 2.5em;">&mdash;</span>
        <!--<p id="total-ether-message" style="font-size:11px;"></p>-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-12-large">
        <h4>
            <strong>Contributions in USD</strong>
        </h4>
        <span id="token_usd" style="font-size: 2.5em;">&mdash;</span>
        <!--<p id="total-usd-message" style="font-size:11px;"></p>-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-12-large">
        <h4>
            <strong>Tokens issued</strong>
        </h4>
        <span id="token_amount" style="font-size: 2.5em;">&mdash;</span>
        <!-- <p id="total-tokens-message" style="font-size:11px;"></p> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, just wondering if you'd be able to help with another bit that I'm stuck with? I can send over link in JSFiddle? :/ Novice stuff to you I reckon..

Comment: Would you like to add another question? You'll get more feedback that way, and increase your rep...

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is `Promise.all()` (in vanilla JavaScript) or `$.when()` (in jQuery).

Here's an updated jQuery fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5L54100/10/

A working vanilla version: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lwo7rs4/8/

In jQuery:

```js
var promise1 = $.get("https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/" + token + "/" + address);
var promise2 = $.get("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice");

$.when(promise1, promise2).then(function(p1Data, p2Data) {
  // do stuff with the data
}).catch(function (error) {
  // error handling
});
```

Vanilla JS (note, using JSON like this you'll also need `response.json()`, see the fiddle and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json):

```js
var promise1 = fetch("https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/" + token + "/" + address);
var promise2 = fetch("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice");

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(combinedData) {
  // do stuff with the data
}).catch(function (error) {
  // error handling
});
```

Basically what's going on is that `$.get` and `fetch` return promises (an object that represents an asynchronous action's state with callbacks to handle different responses such as `success` or `failure`). `when`/`all` itself is a promise that waits for the fulfillment of all the promises it's given or the first promise failure. If the promises it's given are successful, it calls the `then` function. If one of the promises it's given fail, it calls the `catch` function.

Another option is to chain the requests:

```js
var url1 = "https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/" + token + "/" + address;
var url2 = "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice";

fetch(url1)
  .then(function(data1) {
    return fetch(url2);
  })
  .then(function(data2) {
    // do stuff with data1 and data2
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle errors
  });
```

Which looks great in ES6:

```js
const url1 = `https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/${token}/${address}`;
const url2 = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice';

fetch(url1)
  .then(data1 => fetch(url2))
  .then(data2 => /* do stuff with data1 and data2 */)
  .catch(error => /* handle errors */);
```

Promises are super awesome and very confusing. I recommend looking at the resources for fetch to get the general idea before diving further into promises.

Fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Promise.all(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

jQuery.when(): https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/